# Is there any way to check Time Complexity of methods provided by Objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance

Actually sometimes you are required to write some custom code to achieve some functionality, there would be 2 possible approaches there:

1. make your implementation by joining already given methods of
   Objective-c
2. write your custom code

At that point I am confused which code base is better(in performance), that can only be decided if I luckily find `Time-Complexity` of Objective-c methods. So is there any way to know about it?

Comment: Code it the easy way, and then learn/use [*this technique*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771). That will tell you what you should focus on. Until you have more personal experience, you really can't judge in advance what will be a performance problem.

Comment: The wonderful people at objc.io have done some investigating on their own for the Foundation collection types. This is a good reference, though algorithmic complexity should really not be a factor in your decision until a performance problem is noticed: https://www.objc.io/issues/7-foundation/collections/

Answer (score 4):

There are *a lot* of methods and functions you can call in the SDKs for iOS (and other Apple platforms), so this question is perhaps excessively broad.

But a discussion of time complexity is usually about *algorithmic* complexity, so we can restrict our scope to those calls that are the building blocks of algorithms where we measure time as a function of input size — that is, things like collection operations rather than, say, `UIApplication registerForRemoteNotifications`.

By and large, however, Apple doesn't talk much about the computational complexity of the high-level data structures in Cocoa. This probably has something do with Cocoa's design goals being strongly in favor of encapsulation, with simple interfaces hiding powerful, dynamic, and possibly adaptable implementations. Examining CoreFoundation — the open source implementations underlying the central bits of Cocoa, like collections — bears this out. [Here's a great writeup](http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/array.html) on how `NSArray` is sometimes *O(1)* and sometimes not.

There's certainly something to be said for a philosophy where you're not supposed to care about the complexity of the tools you're using — tell it *what* you want to do, not *how* you want it done, and let it optimize performance for you, because it can second-guess you better than you can second-guess yourself. It goes well with a philosophy of avoiding [premature optimization](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth).

On the other hand, there's also some sense to a philosophy of having basic building blocks of enforced, predictable complexity so that you can more easily plan the complexity of the algorithms you build from them. Just to show that Apple seems to do it both ways, it appears this is the philosophy of choice [for the Swift standard library](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/3877d04a735e72aa1be3f8ab21c9902f7ac7b0ff/docs/StdlibAPIGuidelines.rst).